# Calling SignalR Core from Console Client with JWT Authorization Failure

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net-authorization

I have a .net console client calling my SignalR hub.  The hub is running as a Web API and I need to add authorization to it.  So my client calls into IdentityServer and adds the AccessTokenProvider as so:

```
 var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://localhost:53965/Notify", options =>
            {
                options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
            }
            )
            .Build();
```

In the hub setup in the server I have this code which I used by following Microsoft's documents:

```
 services.AddControllers();
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.Audience = "notification";
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                            (path.StartsWithSegments("/Notify")))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };

            });
```

Lastly, I map my endpoints in configure in the startup like this:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();

            endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/Notify"); 
        });
```

When I step through my code for the console client and I get to the JwtBearderEvents OnMessageReceived, the path shows "/Notify/negotiate" then throws the error "Response status code does not indicate success: 401(unauthorized) and stops for both console and web app.  When I do stop in the JwtBearerEvents, it isn't showing the accessToken from the client.

Comment: `the path shows "/Notify/negotiate" then throws the error "Response status code does not indicate success: 401(unauthorized) and stops for both console and web app.` try to move the `[Authorize]` to hub method(s) rather than on hub class and test if it can work.

Comment: I'll give that a try.  Thanks.